# How to match autoref numbering with chapter numbering format?

Tags: hyperref, autoref

The chapter number in `\autoref` doesn't match with chapter number in text.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\filcenter\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\bfseries}%
        {\chaptertitlename\ \Roman{chapter}}%
        {0pt}%
        {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}
    In \autoref{chap:intro}.
    
    I want chapter I, not chapter 1.
    
\end{document}
```

---

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine \thechapter to that labels know the formatting:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\filcenter\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\bfseries}%
        {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}%
        {0pt}%
        {\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}
    In \autoref{chap:intro}.

    I want chapter I, not chapter 1.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With that redefine, all chapter number will changes. I don't want this change in section number, equation number and so on. Is there another way?

Comment: labels will use \thechapter. Redefine the section numbers if they are not to your liking. But why do you want to confuse your reader by using a different numbering in the chapter title and in the sections?